# Replace mulitple Inputs in txt document using batch file

Tags: loops, batch-file, replace, cmd, txt

I am looking for a way to scan a .txt file for mulitple words
and replace them with other words using a batch script.
For example I would like to change two words : {Hello} and {beautiful}

Before:
"**Hello** stack community what a **beautiful** day today"

After:
"**Hi** stack community what a **lovely** day today"

I found a code that could change one input at the time:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set SEARCHTEXT1=Hello
set REPLACETEXT1=Hi 
set SEARCHTEXT2=beautiful
set REPLACETEXT2=lovely

set OUTPUTLINE=
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
SET string=%%A

SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT1%=%REPLACETEXT1%!
echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
)
```

This will only change the value "Hello" to "Hi"
I would also like to replace the other words like "beautiful" to "lovely"

Comment: Change `string` to `modified` in both places. Duplicate the `set modified` line and change `text1` to `text2`. COnsider using preferred syntax `set "var=value"` which prevents stray trailing spaces on the code line from being assigned as a value. Hence you can then substitute for/with `Hi ` in place of `Hi`. Note that the `set "var=!value:string1=string2!"` command is case-insensitive, also that `echo !modified! >>` will append the space between `d` and `>` to each line produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set INTEXTFILE=input.txt
set OUTTEXTFILE=output.txt

set "SEARCHTEXT1=Hello"
set "REPLACETEXT1=Hi"
set "SEARCHTEXT2=beautiful"
set "REPLACETEXT2=lovely"

(for /f "delims=" %%A in (%INTEXTFILE%) do (
    set "string=%%A"
    set "modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT1%=%REPLACETEXT1%!"
    set "modified=!modified:%SEARCHTEXT2%=%REPLACETEXT2%!"
    echo !modified!
)) > %OUTTEXTFILE%
```

This script will replace both "Hello" and "beautiful" in the input file and write the modified text "Hi" and "Lovely" to the output file. Make sure to adjust the file paths and the replacement text as needed for your specific use case.

Comment: @be-the-leaf - if this answer is helpful, mark the tick mark !

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to do the same, specially if the number of replacements is large or varying:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set INTEXTFILE=input.txt
set OUTTEXTFILE=output.txt

rem Define the replacement sets
set "n=0"
for %%a in ("Hello=Hi" "beautiful=lovely") do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "replace[!n!]=%%~a"
)

(for /f "delims=" %%A in (%INTEXTFILE%) do (
    set "string=%%A"
    for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%x in ("!replace[%%i]!") do (
        set "string=!string:%%x=%%y!"
    )
    echo !string!
)) > %OUTTEXTFILE%
```

Comment: Hi. Works this for you?